# Laravel 5 - Automatic view file with form is possible?

Tags: laravel-5

when I run the command "php artisan make:auth" login functionality related stuff created automatically. There are view files also created. Is there any way to generate view files with my model fields, like how tha command is doing??!!

Comment: You can simply modify that view file.

Comment: @nextt1 Hi  nextt1, Thanks for the response. My questions is can I replicate like what the make:auth command. make:auth command is generating view files with the form. Is there a way to do the same for some other models??!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, creating custom `artisan` commands.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#writing-commands